# Selected item should not shown in auto complete list

Tags: json, web-services, jquery-ui, asp.net-ajax, jquery-autocomplete

I am using auto-complete web service sing JSON, If i am selecting a list item that must not be appear again in auto-complete list;

JSON AJAX code:

```
 select: function (event, ui) {
                    var terms = split(this.value);
                    if (terms.length <= 10) {
                        // remove the current input
                        terms.pop();
                        // add the selected item
                        terms.push(ui.item.value);
                        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                        terms.push("");
                        this.value = terms.join(", ");
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        var last = terms.pop();
                        $(this).val(this.value.substr(0, this.value.length - last.length - 0)); // removes text from input
                        $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
                        $(this).addClass("red");
                        $("#warnings").html("<span style='color:red;'>Max skill reached</span>");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
```

I am attaching screenshot also, please see here :
[image: Autocomplete Image]

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle, or at least more code (html, etc.)

Comment: Mind me asking why?  Does it have to go back in the list if the user removes it?

Comment: @Bindrid, I don't know what u r asking, your question is wired for me. srry

Comment: @Fraser, fiddlr code here: [fiddlr Link](https://jsfiddle.net/9cqc5876/1/light/)

Comment: Its not common to remove the selected items out of the list of options so I was wondering why you are.  Btw, there is a plugin called select2 plugin that accomplishes a lot of what I think you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Bindred mentioned in the comments to your question, an easier solution would be to use the Select2 jQuery library. It is not exactly what you are looking for, but as far as UX goes I think it would achieve a similar goal, and it is a breeze to get working.

I have added an example for you to use: https://jsfiddle.net/9cqc5876/9/

**HTML**

```
<select id="txtExpertise" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

**JavaSript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#txtExpertise").prop("disabled", "disabled");

  // do your ajax request for data
  //$.getJSON("../WebServices/WebServiceSkills.asmx/GetAutoCompleteData", function(data) {

    // fake json data
    var data = {"languages": ["Java", "C", "C++", "PHP", "Visual Basic", 
      "Python", "C#", "JavaScript", "Perl", "Ruby"]};

    // populate the select
    $.each(data.languages, function(key, val) {
      $('#txtExpertise')
        .append($("<option></option>")
          .attr("value", key)
          .text(val));
    });

    // activate the select2
    $("#txtExpertise").select2();
    $("#txtExpertise").prop("disabled", false);

  //});
});
```

Comment: Thnx alot @Fraser to help me. Can you provide me Javascript version link for tagenozation? i want autocomplete like tags also

Comment: @Aman the example in jsfiddle already has that, doesn't it? Have a look at the Select 2 examples page. It has lots of options and code examples.

Comment: I know that but, I want to know, what javascript and jquery library file version is good for tags.